# Node.js blockchain bitcoin api

Tags: node.js, bitcoin

So I want to use this: (taken from their API site -> node.js documentation)
https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-node

Recieving payments:
https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-node/blob/master/docs/Receive.md

```
var blockchain = require('blockchain.info');
var identifier = 'myidentifier'; 
var password = 'mypassword';
var myWallet = new blockchain.MyWallet(identifier, password);
var myBTCadress = '14Q3ufL1BUHtWskBKtsshVDATRY65TaJMB';
```

Ok, so the recieving part:

```
var receive = new blockchain.Receive( [confirmations: 1], ? ); // What do I need to put here?
```

Documentation says:
callbackURL: the url to which the callback should be sent (string)

I don't understand what URL it should go to?!

Comment: The API issues a request to blockchain.info. When they finished processing your request, they will call that URL to inform you about the results. So basically the assumption is, that you have some webserver to receive that answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The callback URL should be the one that redirects back to your site.  So setup a callback url with blockchain like...

https://www.yoursite.com/callback/blockchain

Assuming you are using something like express in your app make a route like so.

```
app.get('/callback/blockchain', function (req, res) {

// Stuff here  

});
```

you will prob need to include

```
var https = require('https');
```

That way then you can set up your logic inside for example...

```
// Stuff here
 var options = {
    host : 'api.blockchain.info',
    path : '/some/path/',
    port : 443,
    method : 'GET'
  }
 var request = https.request(options, function(response){
    var body = ""
    response.on('data', function(data) {
      body += data;
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
      res.send(JSON.parse(body));
    });
  });
  request.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('Problem with request: ' + e.message);
  });
  request.end();
```

That will for example output you request in json on whatever page you have your app.get('whateverurl') set to.